# Extreme points of the intersection of the probability simplex and a ball in $\ell_\infty$-norm

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis

Let $n$ and $s$ be two natural numbers such that $1<s<n$. Let $\Delta^n_1$ be the $n$-dimensional probability simplex 
$$
\Delta^n_1 = \Big\{x\in[0,1]^n: \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1\Big\}
$$
and $B^n_\infty(1/s)$ be the ball in $\mathbb R^n$ centered at $0$ and with radius
$1/s$ with respoect to $\ell_\infty$-norm:
$$
B^n_\infty(1/s) = \{x\in\mathbb R^n: \max_i |x_i|\le 1/s\}.
$$
Let $S$ be the finite set composed of all the vectors of $\Delta^n_1$ having exactly $s$ coordinates equal to $1/s$ (uniform probabilities).

**Question:** is it true that the set $\Delta^n_1\cap B^n_\infty(1/s)$ 
is equal to the convex hull of $S$? The inclusion $c.h.(S)\subset \Delta^n_1\cap B^n_\infty(1/s)$ is easy to establish. What about the converse inclusion?

Comment: Use the invariance to permutations of co-ordinates (not to tell the answer itself).

Comment: Still, to be more explicit, consider your sets intersected with $x_1\leqslant\ldots\leqslant x_n$. What do you see?

Comment: I guess you mean that these two sets are equal. However, I fail to prove this equality. At the first sight, it might seem sufficient to write any vector $x\in \Delta_1^n \cap B_\infty^n(1/s)$ with nondecreasing coordinates as $sx_1\mathbf e_1 + s(x_2-x_1)\mathbf e_2 + \ldots + s(x_n-x_{n-1})\mathbf e_n$ for some uniform probability vectors $\{\mathbf e_j\}$, but unfortunately it does not work ...

Comment: An observation i can tell is: In the convex hull of $S$, it can be seen that all the vectors with $\frac{1}{m}$ in $m$ co-ordinates are there for all $m \geq s$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, the two sets are equal. This follows from a famous result often referred to as the Minkowski theorem: any convex polytope is the convex hull of its extreme points.

The intersection $A\triangleq \Delta^n_1\cap B^n_\infty(1/s)$ is a convex polytope. It is easy to check that its extreme points are all the elements of $S$. Therefore, $A=c.h.(S)$.